# Barring a Vote due to conflict of interest

Tags: florida, hoa, conflict-of-interest

Florida HOAs are governed by [FS718.3027](https://www.flsenate.gov/Laws/Statutes/2018/0718.3027) Conflict interest criteria. "Litmus" test comprise (are not necessarily limited to):

> (a) A director or an officer, or a relative of a director or an officer, enters into a contract for goods or services with the association.
>
> (b) A director or an officer, or a relative of a director or an officer, holds an interest in a corporation, limited liability corporation, partnership, limited liability partnership, or other business entity that conducts business with the association or proposes to enter into a contract or other transaction with the association.

That being said, when a board is deciding on an action involving a violation and 2 directors, **that does not quite fit in the "litmus test" described above: there are violations regarding the bylaws and possibly other statues**, what is the basis in law that allows, if not forces, the board to bar said directors' vote?

Answer (score 1):

### [718.3027](https://www.flsenate.gov/Laws/Statutes/2018/0718.3027)(4)

> A director or an officer, or a relative of a director or an officer, who is a party to, or has an interest in, an activity that is a possible conflict of interest, as described in subsection (1), may attend the meeting at which the activity is considered by the board and is authorized to make a presentation to the board regarding the activity. After the presentation, the director or officer, or the relative of the director or officer, must leave the meeting during the discussion of, and the vote on, the activity. A director or an officer who is a party to, or has an interest in, the activity must recuse himself or herself from the vote.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  It helped me to realize that what I wrote and what I thought wrote were two very different things.  Please excuse the error and allow a "mulligan"?  The OP has been amended.  Thank you